# User login session ends with browser closing

Tags: django

Django has authentication module, which works great. There is little problem that once user is loged in, that information is saved for longer period of time. Even user close browser session do not end. Actually, I want that session to end when user close browser.

Is there any way that user's login information is no longer remember once browser is closed

Krish

Comment: You'd need some client-side javascript code to tell your site that the site is being left (browser closed, navigating away, etc...). Without that code, it is impossible to for your site to tell when it's not longer being viewed by the user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this in settings.py:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can pass 0 in

> set_expiry(0)

just like this:

> request.session.set_expiry(0)